# Want multiple search engines available in the Firefox context menu. Constantly switching SEs to set the active SE in context menu is tiresome

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, contextmenu, search-engine

How can I make multiple search engines available in the Firefox context menu. In Firefox 33.0.2, when you right-click a highligted term, only one search engine - the active one in the search box, is active. I am constantly swtiching between my top 3 seach engines - Wikipedia, dictionary.com and Urban Dictionary, depending on what I want to look up. It is tiresome. I would like to be able to choose a subset of my chosen search engines as active in the context menu. Perhaps not all of them. I use some more than others.

Comment: I'll post a snippet which can be turned into an addon that can do this.

Comment: Yes, it's here. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/more-search-engines-in-context/ Still not approved, after quite some time. Next version I gotta replace the prompts with a panel and save the settings so that one
does not have to re-enter choices upon restart and can modify the behavior between restarts.

Comment: I've seen an addon a few days ago that put all search engines as icons in the context menu (in a horizontal row). I don't remember the name though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's copy paste code (from https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/dc2b70918147a491d847)

1. #### You need to enable Environment option for scratchpad. Do this by hitting Ctrl + Shift + I which opens a panel, in this panel click on the Gear icon:

   [image]
2. #### Then check the checkbox for "Enable chrome and add-on debugging":

   [image]
3. #### Then open up scratchpad with Shift + F4. Copy paste the code below. Then in menu bar go to "Environment" menu and select "Browser". Then run the code by hitting Ctrl + R.

Voila. It would be awesome if you could turn this into an addon. Let me know if you need help with it. :) I kind of made it so you'll want to make this an addon, otherwise you have to run this code evrytime you start the browser :P (i dont save your settings to pref system :P so running this code everytime will be annoying :P so motivation to make an addon out of it! :P)

To remove the context menu items comment out everything, and uncomment `doUnregister()`. This will be useful for when you make this into a bootstrap addon.

```
function _loadSearch(searchText, useNewTab, purpose) {
    useNewTab = true;
    purpose = 'contextmenu';
    searchText = this.parentNode.querySelector('#context-searchselect').searchTerms;
    let engine;

    // If the search bar is visible, use the current engine, otherwise, fall
    // back to the default engine.
    /*
    if (isElementVisible(this.searchBar))
      engine = Services.search.currentEngine;
    else
      engine = Services.search.defaultEngine;
    */
    engine = Services.search.getEngineByName(this.getAttribute('engine_name'));

    let submission = engine.getSubmission(searchText, null, purpose); // HTML response

    // getSubmission can return null if the engine doesn't have a URL
    // with a text/html response type.  This is unlikely (since
    // SearchService._addEngineToStore() should fail for such an engine),
    // but let's be on the safe side.
    if (!submission) {
      return null;
    }

    let inBackground = Services.prefs.getBoolPref("browser.search.context.loadInBackground");
    Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').openLinkIn(submission.uri.spec,
               useNewTab ? "tab" : "current",
               { postData: submission.postData,
                 inBackground: inBackground,
                 relatedToCurrent: true });

    return engine;
}


function showMyContexts(e) {
    console.log('pop showing, e:', e)
    var parentContext = e.target;
  //var win = e.view;
  var searchContext = parentContext.querySelector('#context-searchselect');
    if (!searchContext.hasAttribute('hidden')) {
      //var searchTermsQuoted = searchContext.searchTerms;
   //var searchTermsQuoted = searchContext.getAttribute('label').match(/".*"/);
        //show them
      var currentlyVisAccessKeys = parentContext.parentNode.querySelectorAll('#' + parentContext.id + ' > menuitem[accesskey]:not([hidden]):not(.myContextWeev)');
      console.log('currentlyVisAccessKeys:', currentlyVisAccessKeys)
      var usedKeys = [];
      for (var i=0; i<currentlyVisAccessKeys.length; i++) {
          usedKeys.push(currentlyVisAccessKeys[i].getAttribute('accesskey').toUpperCase());
      }
      console.log('usedKeys:', usedKeys);
        var myContexts = parentContext.querySelectorAll('.myContextWeev');
        for (var i=0; i<myContexts.length; i++) {
            myContexts[i].removeAttribute('hidden');
        var engine_name = myContexts[i].getAttribute('engine_name');
      var newLbl = searchContext.getAttribute('label').replace(Services.search.currentEngine.name, engine_name); //win.gNavigatorBundle.getFormattedString("contextMenuSearch", [Services.search.currentEngine.name, 'rawrr']); //myContexts[i].getAttribute('label').replace(/".*"/,  searchTermsQuoted);
        for (var j=0; j<engine_name.length; j++) {
            var tryKey = engine_name[j].toUpperCase();
            if (usedKeys.indexOf(tryKey) == -1) {
                myContexts[i].setAttribute('accesskey', tryKey);
                break;
            }
        }
      myContexts[i].setAttribute('label', newLbl);
      console.log('removing hiddnes')
        }
    }
}

function hideMyContexts(e) {
    console.log('pop hiding')
    var parentContext = e.target;
    //hide them
    var myContexts = parentContext.querySelectorAll('.myContextWeev');
    for (var i=0; i<myContexts.length; i++) {
        myContexts[i].setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
      console.log('hid it')
    }
}

/*start - windowlistener*/
var windowListener = {
    //DO NOT EDIT HERE
    onOpenWindow: function (aXULWindow) {
        // Wait for the window to finish loading
        let aDOMWindow = aXULWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowInternal || Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
        aDOMWindow.addEventListener("load", function () {
            aDOMWindow.removeEventListener("load", arguments.callee, false);
            windowListener.loadIntoWindow(aDOMWindow, aXULWindow);
        }, false);
    },
    onCloseWindow: function (aXULWindow) {},
    onWindowTitleChange: function (aXULWindow, aNewTitle) {},
    register: function () {
        // Load into any existing windows
        let XULWindows = Services.wm.getXULWindowEnumerator(null);
        while (XULWindows.hasMoreElements()) {
            let aXULWindow = XULWindows.getNext();
            let aDOMWindow = aXULWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowInternal || Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
            windowListener.loadIntoWindow(aDOMWindow, aXULWindow);
        }
        // Listen to new windows
        Services.wm.addListener(windowListener);
    },
    unregister: function () {
        // Unload from any existing windows
        let XULWindows = Services.wm.getXULWindowEnumerator(null);
        while (XULWindows.hasMoreElements()) {
            let aXULWindow = XULWindows.getNext();
            let aDOMWindow = aXULWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindowInternal || Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
            windowListener.unloadFromWindow(aDOMWindow, aXULWindow);
        }
        //Stop listening so future added windows dont get this attached
        Services.wm.removeListener(windowListener);
    },
    //END - DO NOT EDIT HERE
    loadIntoWindow: function (aDOMWindow, aXULWindow) {
        if (!aDOMWindow) {
            return;
        }
        var contextSearchselect = aDOMWindow.document.getElementById('context-searchselect');
        if (contextSearchselect) {
            var insertBeforeEl = contextSearchselect.nextSibling;
          var parentContext = contextSearchselect.parentNode; //should be id `contentAreaContextMenu`
          parentContext.addEventListener('popupshowing', showMyContexts, false);
          parentContext.addEventListener('popuphiding', hideMyContexts, false);
          for (var i=0; i<addTheseEngineNamesToContext.length; i++) {
          var myContext = aDOMWindow.document.createElement('menuitem'); //contextSearchselect.cloneNode(true);
          myContext.setAttribute('class', 'myContextWeev');
          myContext.setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
          myContext.setAttribute('engine_name', addTheseEngineNamesToContext[i]);
              myContext.addEventListener('command', _loadSearch, false);
          parentContext.insertBefore(myContext, insertBeforeEl);
        }
        }
    },
    unloadFromWindow: function (aDOMWindow, aXULWindow) {
        if (!aDOMWindow) {
            return;
        }
        var contextSearchselect = aDOMWindow.document.getElementById('context-searchselect');
        if (contextSearchselect) {
          var parentContext = contextSearchselect.parentNode; //should be id `contentAreaContextMenu`
          parentContext.removeEventListener('popupshowing', showMyContexts, false);
          parentContext.removeEventListener('popuphiding', hideMyContexts, false);
          var myContexts = parentContext.querySelectorAll('.myContextWeev');
          for (var i=0; i<myContexts.length; i++) {
            parentContext.removeChild(myContexts[i]);
          }
        }
    }
};
/*end - windowlistener*/

var addTheseEngineNamesToContext = [];

function doRegister() {
var engines = Services.search.getVisibleEngines();
var engineNames = [];
engines.forEach(function(engine) {
  engineNames.push(engine.name);
});


var check = {value: false};
var input = {value: "1"};
var result = Services.prompt.prompt(null, "Engine Count", "How many search engines to add to the conext menu? (Max: " + engines.length + ")", input, null, check);
if (result) {
  if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value == '') {
    Services.prompt.alert(null, "Error", "Must enter a number");
  } else {
    if (input.value > 0 && input.value <= engines.length) {
      for (var i=0; i<input.value; i++) {
        var selected = {};
        var result = Services.prompt.select(null, "Select Engine " + (i + 1), "Select the engine to add to menu in position " + (i + 1), engineNames.length, engineNames, selected);
        if (result) {
          console.log(selected);
          addTheseEngineNamesToContext.push(engineNames[selected.value]);
          if (i == input.value-1) {
            Services.prompt.alert(null, "ok windowListener.register", addTheseEngineNamesToContext);
            windowListener.register();
          }
        } else {
          Services.prompt.alert(null, "Cancelled", "Cancelled");
        }
      }

    } else {
      Services.prompt.alert(null, "Error", "You only have " + engines.length + " search engines, must enter a number between 1 and " + engines.length);
    }
  }
}
}

function doUnregister() {
    windowListener.unregister();
}

doRegister();
//doUnregister();
```

Comment: A nice touch to this would be, on popupshowing you go through the visible elements in the menu and get their `accesskey`s and then to your context menu items assign it an accesskey that is not already taken by the currently visible menu items. If you need help on how to do this let me know, this is real easy 10min of work max.

Comment: Thanks, Noitdart. Works for me. The only tiny little issue is that the first search engine appears twice, then the others. My first test was to select three search engines - I get #1 2x, #2 1x and #3 1x. Otherwise, works like a charm. I will package this into an add-on as soon as I figure that out. Cheers/thanks.

Comment: Noitidart! Can't edit my answer if I realized I misspelled your name > 5 minutes after commenting. Sigh...

Comment: No problem thanks though about the name :) The reason the first one comes up twice is because the usual "Currently Selected" search engine is there. So if whatever is currently selected in the search box will show there, test it out :) follow the guides/templates here to copy paste into your own addon and let me know if u need help :) https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/51b62b356b3a21010a4d

Comment: Will do, thanks for everything, I WILL get this done, just bear with me, I'm a bit slower but evernually get around to it. I was thinking myabe the first is there 2x as due to one already being selected, but too late to retract! Cheers. thanks, this has been/is fun.

Comment: Did you try changing the the currently selected engine in the search bar? Then you'll see its not 2x its a different one. If you want we can make this addon togather over TeamViewer, its real fast and simple. We can add a preference to hide the currently selected engine menu item. But im busy with lots of other stuff so u'll need to take charge :)

Comment: also never too late to retract, i dont understand what do you want to retract?

Comment: @SLiss how's this going were you able to make it into an add-on yet? :)

Comment: Yes, I was able to make the add-on. 

It's here: [link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/more-search-engines-in-context/)

Comment: Super work man!!! Every startup though its prompting, we should make it remember by using preference system and also create an options panel for it. :)